# Eclipse Project Types Definition/Configuration

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am trying to work with a modified version of eclipse that has it's own different project types. For some project types when I Create a project, restart and then delete(with the delete from disc not checked) the project I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/projectName' does not exist.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:341)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:215)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:147)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessibleAndLocal(Resource.java:221)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.touch(Resource.java:1949)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.touch(Project.java:1403)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.execute(SetContainerOperation.java:122)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.setJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:3901)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.JREContainerInitializer.initialize(JREContainerInitializer.java:48)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2214)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$6.run(JavaModelManager.java:2144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2160)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:1319)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2747)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2026)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaScriptCore.java:2655)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:32)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2015-07-06 13:39:58.865
!MESSAGE Resource '/projectName' does not exist.

My suspicion is that eclipse does not recognize that as a project or something. So the question is the following : Does anybody know how does eclipse defines the acceptable/available project types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace shows that there is no folder `projectName` in the workspace, so it does not look like the project exists at all.

The contents of the `.project` file in the project folder defines what 'natures' and 'builders' a project has. For example a Java plug-in project `.project` file might look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>projectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.pde.ds.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

The `IProjectDescription` interface provides APIs for setting these values.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick reply. Yes I know that the  stack trace shows that there is no folder projectName in the workspace but in fact there is so this is what complicates the situation a lot. As a mutter of fact when use debug mode I can see at some point checkExists method being called with flag= -1 do you have any idea what this could imply ?

Comment: -1 is just the default flag used if no special checks are required. If you did not use the `IProject.create` API to create the project you might get errors like this.

Comment: Well  now I know that my problem is that I don't know how this org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui plugin is activated during eclipse initialization whenever a project with this org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature nature already exists in the workspace !