# org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui activation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide

I want to know how does this "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui" plugin is being activated  during eclipse initialization whenever a project with this: "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature" nature already exists in the workspace!

My problem is the following : when a eclipse starts this org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui plug in is at starting state until some other plugin loads one of it's classes. One way to start it for example is by creating a javascript project which has this org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature nature. After creating the project though if you restart eclipse the project already exists in the workspace and thus the org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui plugin is at active state exactly after eclipse starts, in my case though even if I have created the project and restart eclipse the org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui plugin is at starting state and not active.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'activation' you mean the various menu items, property pages and such that appear - that is done by testing the nature id in the 'enabledWhen' part of the definition in the plugin.xml. For example one of the property page definitions:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
  <page
        name="%cleanUpPageName"
        category="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.propertyPages.CodeStylePreferencePage"
        class="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.preferences.CleanUpPreferencePage"
        id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.propertyPages.CleanUpPreferencePage">
     <enabledWhen>
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                    value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
         </adapt>         
     </enabledWhen>
     <keywordReference id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.cleanup"/>
  </page>
```

which enables the page for a project with the `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature` nature id

Comment: Well once again thanks a lot for the assistance, But Since I use the same exactly plugin I don't think my problem lies in the plugin.xml file. I rephrase the question and hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Why do you want it to be started during initialization? It is normal for plugins to be started when they are needed by something in their plugin.xml

Comment: Well that is the point I need it to start during initialization only when a project with org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature nature already exist in the workspace because if not when I try to delete the project i get the error that I posted in this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245424/eclipse-project-types-definition-configuration/31245644?noredirect=1#comment50489848_31245644) and from my understanding this is how normal eclipse instance handles it !

Comment: And by saying already exist in the workspace I mean I suppose to see that in my project explorer after I start eclipse !